# Ask question about usage of the words "consent" and "whereby"

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to use the verb "consent" in the meaning of "to agree" not "to permit". Is the following sentence is correct? how about the use of "whereby"?

The man **consent**s to the plan **whereby** the dining hall offers meals prepared by culinary students at the end week of each semester **for two reasons**.

Comment: Yes, _consent_ and _whereby_ are used correctly. It's not entirely clear whether there are two reasons for his consent or for the offer of meals.

Comment: I'd like to give reasons for his consent. Can you have a suggestion?

Comment: Either recast as two sentences, or place a comma after _plan_ and another after _semester_ to separate out the clause describing the plan.